# Import Firefox Bookmarks From Second Hard Drive

Tags: firefox, data-recovery, bookmarks

I had an old dell laptop that broe and was not usable in order to make a backup of my data, so instead I removed it's HDD, RAM, and WIFI card and threw the rest away.

I have managed to restore most of my data by opening the drive's volume in a windows 10 laptop and copying my files to the new laptop. There is one thing left to do however, and that is restore my bookmarks from the old firefox installation somehow. I cannot see anything in the firefox folder or in my favorites folder (I think firefox uses a weird way of storing bookmarks rather than one file per bookmark.)

I don't think I made a backup by using firefox's export bookmarks feature so can I still get my  old bookmarks back? if so, how?

Comment: Just copy what's inside the mozilla/firefox folder to the exact some location in the new PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [bookmarks for recent Firefox version](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite)s are in

> C:\Users\ *username* \AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ *ProfileID*.default\places.sqlite

If you only want bookmarks, copy just that file to your new profile, but if you also want to copy extensions, passwords and other customization, bring over all files and subfolders in the profile.

You can browse the bookmarks with a [SQLite viewer](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases/tag/v3.10.1).
[image: Firefox places.sqlite]